# Drag and Drop List Items (with multi selection)

Tags: mysql, json, listbox

I need populate the ListBox with items from JSON data, dynamic and coming from Asp.Net and MySQL database.

I've come across some snippets of code on the internet but none seem to be working with my needs.

I don't have error but the ListBox is empty.

My code below.

How to do resolve this?

Thanks!

```
protected string GetJsonData()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM City ORDER BY NAME DESC LIMIT 5;";
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
        {
            List<ListItem> customers = new List<ListItem>();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(new ListItem
                    {
                        Value = sdr["Name"].ToString(),
                        Text = sdr["Name"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
            con.Close();

            JavaScriptSerializer jsSer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string str = jsSer.Serialize(customers);
            return str;
        }
    }


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //Get data and fill first box
            var $json = <% =GetJsonData() %>;
            pageload($json);
        });
    </script>

   <div id="list1" class="connectedSortable">
       <asp:ListBox ID="lstCustomers" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
   </div>
   <div id="list2" class="connectedSortable">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you can read the database query into a reader and fill the objects into a list, like this:

```
public class Movie
{
    public string MovieID { get; set; }
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public string MovieLength { get; set; }
    public string MovieDesc { get; set; }
}


List<Movie> listOfMovies = new List<Movie>();

using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=balder.ucn.dk;Initial Catalog=dmaa0213_6;********"))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(connection))
    {
        cmd.CommandString = "SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY MovieId";
        connection.Open();
        using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteDataReader())
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                Movie item = new Movie();
                item.MovieId = reader.GetInt32(0);
                item.MovieName = reader.GetString(1);
                item.MovieLength = reader.GetString(2);
                item.MovieDesc = reader.GetString(3);
                listOfMovies.Add(item);
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```